# Appending values to a CLOB in an 'after update' trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

```
CREATE TABLE COPPER_TAN_META
(
   ID decimal(22,0) PRIMARY KEY,
   NOTES clob,
   ERROR varchar2(2000)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C0070016 ON COPPER_TAN_META(ID);
```

Before update

```
ID  ERROR   NOTES
20  <null>  27-APR-21 08.48.18 AM - XML is not a full-text article;
```

Update

```
update COPPER_TAN_META set error = 'trigger warning' where id = 20;
```

With trigger, I'd like to see this:

```
ID  ERROR            NOTES
20  trigger warning 27-APR-21 08.48.18 AM - XML is not a full-text article; <timestamp> - trigger warning;
```

My trigger doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER copper_error_appends_to_note
  AFTER UPDATE of error on COPPER_TAN_META
  for each row
begin
  IF :new.error is not null THEN
    :new.notes := :old.notes || localtimestamp(0) || ' - ' || :new.error || '; ';
  END IF;
end;
/
```

```
Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'B026.COPPER_ERROR_APPENDS_TO_NOTE' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

This works fine using a normal update statement, like

```
update copper_tan_meta
set notes = notes || localtimestamp(0) || ' - ' || :fileError || '; ' 
where id = :tanMetaId
```

I'm running this on SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***new*** values cannot be changed for `AFTER` trigger type, but possible for `BEFORE`
- `localtimestamp` without argument might be used within the direct concatenation, but `localtimestamp` with `precision` argument such as `localtimestamp(0)` could be used within a SQL statement.

So, rewrite the code block as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER copper_error_appends_to_note
  BEFORE UPDATE OF ERROR ON copper_tan_meta
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE    
    ts TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  SELECT localtimestamp(0) INTO ts FROM dual;
  IF :new.error IS NOT NULL THEN
    :new.notes := :old.notes || ts || ' - ' || :new.error || '; ';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: There is one small issue: the formatting of `ts` isn't the same as it would be. Outside the trigger, `localtimestamp(0)` will not have trailing zeros, but it does in your solution.

Comment: Then see [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F) to see how to format the timestamp rather than taking the current system default.